# jdk 6 https connections not getting cleaned up / leaking?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have a standalone app which appears to have a memory leak in it related to https url connections. It's basically a while-loop that uses URLConnection to post to a site. When I do a heap dump, I can see tens of thousands of instances of:

```
java.net.URL;
sun.net.wwww.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection;
sun.net.wwww.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl;
```

so it appears like each connection the app has made since it started has leaked. The code skeleton of my app looks like:

```
while (true) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(...);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    try {
        out.write(bytes);
    } finally {
       out.close();
    }
}
```

The connection code is actually from google's push notification service library (boiled it down to what they're doing), full code is here:

https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.java#152

so it's more like:

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;

while (true) {
    Sender sender = new Sender(...);
    sender.sendNoRetry(new Message(...));
}
```

I think this is a problem with my platform - I had this same app running on a windows machine and didn't have a problem. I also have a few other similar apps which just post to a url and close their stream, and they run out of memory as well in the same way. I haven't captured any heap dumps on them yet, just realized the connection leaks are probably the common problem to all of them.

I'm on Ubuntu with jdk 1.6.0_30.

Is there something I'm missing, is there some sort of java ssl session cache that I need to explicitly cleanup etc?

Thank you

Comment: You might be hitting http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6745052

Comment: Please ensure that you disconnect the connection by invoking conn.disconnect() method.

Comment: Hmm that might be the bug I'm hitting. @user748316, I can't call conn.disconnect() because I'm using these third party libraries which I don't have any control over. So if I use java 7, that should solve the problem? Looks like that bug was fixed in java 7.

Comment: Well I haven't run into this again after updating to java 7 JRE, and recompiling against jdk 7. So I'll mark this as fixed.

Comment: @vanza can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?